# js stacking by class on button

Tags: javascript, class, sorting, button

http://jsfiddle.net/Ad7GV/19/

```
<div id="10" class="owoc">banan</div>
<div id="9" class="owoc">ananas</div>
<div id="8" class="owoc">fasola</div>
<div id="7" class="owoc">pomarancz</div>
<div id="6" class="owoc">winogrono</div>
<div id="5" class="owoc">ogorek</div>
<div id="4" class="owoc">mango</div>
<div id="3" class="owoc">seler</div>
<div id="2" class="owoc">cebula</div>
<div id="1" class="owoc">kiwi</div>

<button onclick="sortABC()">sortuj alfabetycznie</button>

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].className === "owoc") {
       filtered.push(elements[i]);
    }  
}
var sorted = filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML; 
});

var parent = elements[0].parentNode;

for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    parent.appendChild(sorted[i]);
}
```

could anyone show me how to hook up this script to sort the list onclick not onload? and also i dont know why the button is appearing on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the function sortABC() on click event, but you don't define it as a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ad7GV/20/

```
var sortABC = function(){
    var elements = document.getElementById('elements').children;
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].className === "owoc") {
           filtered.push(elements[i]);
        }  
    }
    var sorted = filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
       return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML; 
    });

    var parent = elements[0].parentNode;

    for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        parent.appendChild(sorted[i]);
    }
}
```

In order to not sort the button too, you can wrap sortered elements in a container, and retrieve only children of this container :

```
<div id = "elements">
    <div id="10" class="owoc">banan</div>
    <div id="9" class="owoc">ananas</div>
    <div id="8" class="owoc">fasola</div>
    <div id="7" class="owoc">pomarancz</div>
    <div id="6" class="owoc">winogrono</div>    
    <div id="5" class="owoc">ogorek</div>
    <div id="4" class="owoc">mango</div>
    <div id="3" class="owoc">seler</div>
    <div id="2" class="owoc">cebula</div>
    <div id="1" class="owoc">kiwi</div>
</div>
<button onclick="sortABC()">sortuj alfabetycznie</button>
```